# Why doesn't Typescript give an error on this discriminating union return type

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I'm curious why typescript is not giving an error for the return type of the `test1` function, whereas for the `test2` function it is.

I would assume typescript is capable of determining the wrong return value for `test1` as it can for `test2`.

```
interface A {
  status: 'a'
  data: {
    value: string
  }
}

interface B {
  status: 'b'
}

type AB = A | B

function test1(arg: 'foo' | 'bar'): AB {
  // this doesn't give a TS error, where it is actually wrong  
  return {
    status: arg === 'foo' ? 'b' : 'a',
    data: {
      value: 'hello'
    }
  }
}

function test2(arg: 'foo' | 'bar'): AB {
  if(arg === 'foo') {
    return {
      status: 'a',
      data: {
        value: 'hello`'
      }
    }
  }
  // This does give an error (which I would expect)
  return {
    status: 'b',
    data: {
      value: 'hello'
    }
  }
}
```

[Link to TS Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQzkDOYcYArgQFzIDkc1u+AJiXFdnvsgG5wA2pEKkSigA5g2QBfXNJy5QkWIhQAhTBKIlyVagCN6OWbjABPAA4pUagLxpkAH2QrcuGKRAIwwAPYhkkIgBGAAo4KFEdGG9vagcaXTDqAEoqK3UOKAgyKD92TkJiMkpkMNFkawqaKJjkAH542J06ABoJJhY2Ns4efkEaAAsIXl4Yrtl8WSMcNw8vX38IIgAmUPDI6NjHPUSUtDU85GAYVbKK22pq5PT8zOzcrvxNIqbqVo585mJO9-zuPgEdINht4AAYGX5SMYScbIW6kHLXThPbQNN4fDqI-I9AEDIYjcGcGGTIA)

**Update:**
If this is "by design" as @wonderflame mentions in the comment would there be an alternative way where you don't have to explicitly return each type?

Comment: This is how the typescript is designed since you are not mentioning explicitly which discriminated union to return and there are no conflicts between the unions. For example, if you would add `data: {value: number}` you would get the error. Does this address your question, If yes I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Interesting, if you put it in a variable first, then return that var, there will be an error.

Comment: @wonderflame, I'm aware that returning `{value: number}` would result in an error. I was hoping there would be a more elaborate answer then "this is how TS is designed". Perhaps the follow up question would there be an alterative to writing each return explicitly. (will update the question)

Comment: Why do you say that the lack of error in `test1` is "wrong"? The compiler is smart enough to know that the returned object literal (which has a property `status` of the inferred type `'a' | 'b'`) can satisfy _either_ of the return types, so allows it. There is no problem with an object having additional properties, but Typescript will try to prevent you declaring unknown properties on object literals when it can correctly detect what type the object literal is meant to be. In the case of `test2`, it knows that the second object _must_ be of type `B`, so complains about the spurious `data`.

Comment: If you want `B` to *prohibit* `data`, you can do so [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/W47Oem) and then the compiler will think the return value is wrong.  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, yes, that does achieve what I want, I actually came up with something similar but used `undefined` instead of `never`, but using `never` seems more accurate. If you write an answer I will mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's object types are *open* and *extendible*, not *sealed* or *exact* (using Flow terminology, and as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)).  Since `B`'s definition makes no mention whatsoever of the `data` property, it means that a `B` *may or may not contain a `data` property*.  It doesn't *require* one, but it doesn't *prohibit* one either.

This is complicated by the fact that TypeScript will sometimes perform [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) on object literals, but that feature is more of a linter warning and is meant to prevent you from setting properties the compiler will probably lose track of. It is *not* really meant to make object types sealed or exact.

Excess property checking does usually kick in for [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), but your approach in `test1` of making the `status` property itself a union confused things enough to not have it activate.  Again, you're not really supposed to rely on excess property checking for correctness.

---

If you want `B` to consistently prohibit a `data` property, you will need to change `B`'s definition to say that explicitly.  Well, TypeScript doesn't actually let you *prohibit* a property.  The closest you can get is to make it an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) of a type like [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  This means the property will either be missing, or present without a defined value (depending on your compiler options that could include `undefined`; see [`--exactOptionalPropertyTypes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) for more info).

Like this:

```
interface B {
  status: 'b'
  data?: never; // <-- no data on B
}
```

And now things start behaving the way you expect:

```
function test1(arg: 'foo' | 'bar'): AB {
  return { // error!
    status: arg === 'foo' ? 'b' : 'a',
    data: {
      value: 'hello'
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQzkDOYcYArgQFzIDkc1u+AJiXFdnvsgG5wA2pEKkSigA5g2QBfXNJy5QkWIhQAhTBKIlyVagCN6HZsQD8VEBC7QA3MgD0t5AB4AtM+QgA9siNxkHkMgqMri4YACeAA4oqGoAvGjIAD6BITgwpCAIYMD+yJBEAIwAFHBQojowHh7USTS6pdQAlFQx6hxQEGRQARh2DtBQHlAAhBL4mmSUyKWiyLHzNJXVyMZ1NTp0ADRj3ixsO-g8-II0ABYQvLzVO7L4srK46ZnZuflgAEwlZRVVNcl6DWaaDU7HwwBgyC+s3m8WoSyabU4yA6XR6B0IxEmG2o2w4SJ8+zxSO4fAEOnOlw8AAMDMSpDcJLdkZ1SN1EZwJto1rj8Xt2UijmSzhcrrTOEz7kA)